# Failure executing javac: Compilation failure

Tags: maven

Same project Building using maven on two different laptops. On one its running good and on one its showing error.

Status: Both Systems are of same configurations.

```
C:\Users\admin>mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530)
Java version: 1.6.0_43
Java home: C:\Installers\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "amd64" Family: "windows"
```

Command used: **mvn clean install -DskipTests=true**

Error:

```
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\admin\HeliosWorkspace\...\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.    

        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor
.java:715)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifec
ycleExecutor.java:556)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.
java:535)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultL
ifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleE
xecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java
:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I even tried even deleting everything like creating .m2 folder again.

Comment: Execute `mvn -X clean install -DskipTests=true` to see debug output and paste it here.

Comment: check your Java_Home variable

Comment: Also check if compiler plugin is configured properly.

Comment: Can you update what is value of your JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: running maven in debug mode -X helped me now its resolved.

Comment: @JyotiPrakash please explain how debug mode helped you, I have the same problem.

Comment: -X command shows the detailed view of whats happening while executing the 'mvn' command. I found the missing jar details.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue, and resolved it with some troubleshooting.

This is actually a DOS error message when you try to execute a file but enter an invalid path to it.

```
C:\Users\me>c:\asdf\foo.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Maven is trying to execute javac to compile your code but doesn't have the correct path.For many setups, you will need to check the path to your compiler in your pom.xml. Go to the cmd prompt and copy and paste it in and make sure its a valid path.

For a setup that uses settings.xml profiles to define some global configurations on different JAVA_HOMEs such as the below example, ensure the paths are correct in each variable, the profile with these variables is active (activeProfile tags can ensure this), and is correctly referenced in your pom.xml

```
    <!-- settings.xml -->
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>compiler-versions</id> 
        <properties>
            <JAVA_1_5_HOME>C:/java/jdk1.5.0_16</JAVA_1_5_HOME>
            <JAVA_1_6_HOME>C:/java/jdk1.6.0_43</JAVA_1_6_HOME>
            <JAVA_1_7_HOME>C:/java/jdk1.7.0_55</JAVA_1_7_HOME>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>


     <activeProfiles>
        <!-- make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>compiler-versions</activeProfile>
     </activeProfiles>
```

pom.xml snippet:

```
    <!-- pom.xml -->
    <!-- ... -->
            <build>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>${JAVA_1_6_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                    <meminitial>256m</meminitial>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <!--encoding>UTF-8</encoding-->
                    <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, now its working:

```
mvn -X clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Debug mode is very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and i found that settings.xml @ Maven_home/conf or C:\Users\.m2\settings.xml was pointing to a wrong JDK path, correcting which did fix the issue. The error message which is printed above is  actually spot on which says "Failure executing javac" which means Maven did not find the JDK.

Thanks
Hithesh

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but i think this answer will help people in the future:

> Java home: C:\Installers\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre

You are using the JRE instead of the JDK. just remove "\jre" from your java home

Answer (score 0):

you could use the example indicated by @jiman, however if it is used on different computers, the JDK installation path should not be burned in the pom or in the configuration files, because it could vary.

To resolve this conflict, what I did was change the JAVA_HOME environment variable from the git console, assigning it the path of my JDK installation as follows:

export JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301'

Keep in mind that it only works per session, that is, every time a new console is opened, the same must be done.

Answer (score -1):

Check your POM File and ensure you have the right environment variables for MVN and Java